# Accessing MySQL that is installed in Ubuntu guest from Windows host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed MySQL in VirtualBox with Ubuntu as guest OS.

Now I want to access this MySQL tables from the Windows 7 host?

Comment: be specific in your question, [edit] & mention what the exact error message is, what problems you're facing and what you've done

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue the connection? If so http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Or can you not connect at all - if so a firewall.

To be honest, there are so many things which could be the reason, it is nearly impossible to know where to begin, let alone how to answer this - maybe you should qualify the question better?